# No sound on imac27 latest

Tags: sound, alsa

I bought an imac a couple of weeks ago and installed both arch and ubuntu on it. Neither is able to play sound.

I did add `options snd-hda-intel model=imac27_122` to `/etc/modprobe.d/asla-base.conf` but with no success.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu Community Help Wiki:

**[Intel_iMac 27"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Intel_iMac#Sound)**

Since kernel 2.6.38, the HD audio model **imac27** is available.

The following line must be inserted at the end of the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-hda-intel model=imac27
```

Force reload alsa configuration:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Then unmute and adjust volume of front speaker and Surround Speaker with the help of :

```
alsamixer
```

Then reboot.

Btw, in your post you're using `options snd-hda-intel model=imac27_122`, change the model to the suggestion in the Wiki, also you can try with `options snd-hda-intel model=auto`.

Hope it helps, good luck.

Comment: I already tried all of these options, and none of them worked. I believe the problem has to do with my audio card being new, so it is not yet supported by the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test on Ubuntu but [it worked on an iMac 18,3 on Fedora 37](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/734497/245022).

Install [this module](https://github.com/egorenar/snd-hda-codec-cs8409).

```sh
# clone the repo of the module
git clone https://github.com/egorenar/snd-hda-codec-cs8409.git

# make and install
cd snd-hda-codec-cs8409
make
sudo make install
```

reboot.